# Array of pointers to char arrays

Tags: c

I am confused about the following line of code:

```
char* words[] = { "aaa", "bbbb", "ccccc", "dddddd" };
```

The way I understand, each word is first stored and then each position of the array `words` will point then to the first character of each word. How are these strings stored? Is there dynamic allocation going on here or are these words stored on the stack?

If they are stored on the stack, in which way are they stored? For instance, if I print some of the contents of `words` as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    char* words[] = { "aaa", "bbbb", "ccccc", "dddddd" };
    printf("\n\n(*words)[0] = %s", words[0]);
    printf("\n\n(*words)[0]+1 = %s", words[0]+1);
    return 0;
}
```

instead of printing `aaa` and `bbbb`, what I get is `aaa` and `aa`. I do not really understand what is the reason for this since, the way I see it, `words[0]+1` should point to the string `bbbb` and not to the second character of `aaa`. What is going on here?

Comment: Are you confusing `words[0] + 1`, `(words + 1)[0]` and `words[1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the way I see it, words[0]+1 should point to the string bbbb and not to the second character of aaa

No. `words[0]` is a char pointer itself - it's perfectly fine that you get the second character of "aaa" by adding one to it. What you want is `words + 1` or `&words[0] + 1` which will correctly be "bbbb".

Also, the strings themselves are allocated upon launching the executable and they're probably put in the data or bss section of the binary by the linker. Also, when you declare and initialize `words`, it'll be allocated on the stack as any other automatic array and its items will be assigned to pointers to the beginning of each string constant.

Comment: I see. I actually tried doing things such as `words[1][1] = 'u'` to change `bbbb` into `bubb`, but `bbbb` stays the same after I change it (!). Is this then because the strings are read only (I am assuming they are since they are rvalues)?

Comment: @curvature yes they are. Be glad it didn't crash - modifying string constants is UB.

Answer (score 15):

this is like..

[image]

since words an array of character of pointers so each array index of words will hold the 
address of the string literal ,i.e. base address of the string literals
if you will print

```
 printf("%s",words[0])// index 0 will print aaa.
```

Answer (score 6):

The difference is because `words[0]+1` is not the same as `words[0+1]`.

The former points to the second character in `words[0]`, while the latter points to the second word.

Answer (score 3):

words[0] points to the first 'a' in "aaa".

words[0]+1 moves that pointer along by one character, so it comes to point at the second 'a'.

words[1] points at "bbbb"

words[1]+1 points "bbb", e.g. the second 'b' in "bbbb".

Answer (score 1):

The literal strings are stored in static memory. Their actual location is implementation-dependent but literal strings are stored *somewhere*, typically in the data portion of the executable - this is neither dynamic nor stack allocation. Your array then contains pointers to these locations.

> words[0]+1 should should point to the string bbbb and not to the second character of aaa.

This simply isn't how array indexing works. You index the array of strings with `words[0]`, now you have a string, and any operations apply to that string. You can't do arithmetic with array indices outside the subscript. To get to the string `"bbbb"`, you would use `words[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Both stack and heap space is dynamically allocated -- that is, they are allocated at run time. Is your compiled code dynamically allocated, on the heap or stack? Obviously neither. Storage for constants is similar to storage for code ... they are stored in the executable on disk and loaded into read-only memory. (Note for pedants: this is how things are done in a typical implementation; it is not mandated by the language standard.)

`words[0]` is the address of the first 'a' of "aaaa". Adding 1 to that address should surely yield the address of the second 'a' of "aaaa". The address of "bbbb" is way over at `words[1]`.

In the format of your printf you have "(*words)[0]", but that's different. `*words` is the same as `words[0]`. `(*words)[0]` is the same as `**words`, which is the first 'a' (not its address) of "aaaa". You would print `(*words)[0]` with `%c`, not `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

words[0] returns the address of aaa.  Adding 1 to that increments the address to point to the second a.

Do you mean to have words[0+1]?

That should give you what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* words[] = { "aaa", "bbbb", "ccccc", "dddddd" };
```

All the 4 strings have static storage duration and are allocated prior to the program startup.

In the initializer, the arrays are converted to pointers to `char` and the `words` array is initialized with the pointer values.